# iterating through a json object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a really hard time trying to find a way to iterate through this JSON object in the way that I'd like. I want to separate the token in a variable and the user details in other variables. I'm using only Javascript here.

First, here's the object

```
{
  "token": "517b27a84a4d373a636e323a9572a0ab43883291", 
  "user": {
    "credential_id":"1",
    "name":"name",
    "password":"password",
    "age":"25",
    "email":"kalay@peelay.com",
    "img_src":"043008thmy.jpg",
    "user_type":"0",
    "username":"kalay"
  }
}
```

Comment: try using `for (var i in object){}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse` which deserializes `JSON` to produce a JavaScript object or array.

This example uses `JSON.parse` to deserialize `JSON` into the `json_obj` object.

```
var json_obj = JSON.parse(json);
var token = json_obj.token;
var username = json_obj.user.username;
var email = json_obj.user.email;
```

Answer (score 0):

simply try

```
var token = obj.token;
var user_credentials = obj.user.credential_id;
```

similarly you can access values of other attributes in the `obj`

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the contents via:

```
var token = obj["token"];
```

or

```
var username = obj["user"]["username"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the key value to iterate, my method is a little bit static, because it requires that you know "token" und "user" exit in your json.

```
var token = "",
    user = {};

for(var key in jsonObject){
 if(key == "token"){
    token = jsonObject[key];
 }
 if(key == "user"){
    user = jsonObject[key];
 }
}
```